# Фигурный элемент в вёрстке

Tags: html, css

Как называется белый фигурный элемент на скриншоте и как его сверстать?

[image: скриншот]

Comment: нарисуйте какой из них?

Comment: В нижней половине скриншота, дугообразный. В элементе располагаются цифры 15, 230 и т.д.

Answer (score 8):

Добавьте блоку `border-radius`, с его размером можете поэксперементировать:

```css
div{
  height:70vh;
  background-color:gold;
  border-radius:0 0 50% 50%/0 0 40px 40px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы имеете ввиду белый фон ?
Можно сделать блоку с картинкой(сидящим парням) , дать border-radius (нужное значение) , только скашивать нижние углы.